# Do I need multiple statefulsets for each rack/zone when using topologyspreadconstraint consider 2 cases where I have a single or multiple datacenter?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

Currently I deployed Cassandra in k8s without multi-rack in single/multiple data-centers using single rack.

Now I am planning to deploy Cassandra across multiple racks in single/multiple DCs. I am planning to use `topologySpreadConstraints` for this. I will define to constraints one for `zone` and another for `node` and will add nodes label accordingly. Here is the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/) which I am referring for above implementation.

The idea behind this is to achieve High Availability (HA) so that if one rack goes down my service will be available & pods should not be scheduled on other racks. When it's restored, pods should be restored back on it.

But I am not sure how many `statefulset (sts)` I should use?

1. Should I use one `sts` if I have one DC and N `sts` if I have N DC?
2. Or, I should always use N `sts` if I have N `Racks` in each DC?

**Sample Code**
Consider, I have 3 nodes, 3 racks and am trying to deploy 2 pods on each rack and node. And added zone & node labels on all nodes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
      foo: bar
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 6 # by default is 1
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: node-pu
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: zone-pu
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
   ... # removed other config
```

Comment: https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/do-i-need-multiple-statefulsets-for-each-rack-zone-when-using-topologyspreadconstraint-consider-2-cases-where-i-have-a-single-or-multiple-datacenter/17169

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you're not using the cass-operator in [K8ssandra](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05) since the `CassandraDatacenter` in cass-operator owns the StatefulSets.

You don't need to create a StatefulSet for each logical Cassandra rack. It should be able to schedule pods in different availability zones.

But I would suggest creating a different StatefulSet for each logical Cassandra DC so you can control how the pods get scheduled across racks/zones. Cheers!

Comment: Thank @erick-ramirez for sharing this info. Adding one more [link](https://forum.k8ssandra.io/t/in-rack-topology-why-affinity-rules-are-preferred-over-topologyspreadconstraint/271/) for reference so that user can relate why I asked this question.

Comment: How Statefulset will manage deployment of nodes of different racks?

Comment: @Pushpendra K8ssandra doesn't support `topologySpreadConstraints` yet because it is new and was only marked stable in K8s 1.19. K8ssandra supports K8s all the way back to 1.16 so we can't introduce any K8s feature that is not backwards-compatible. Cheers!